# Excel VBA Saving with Variable Name

Tags: excel, vba

Soo.... having a problem saving the excel with as the name i want it to generate.. it keeps saving as "FALSE"... from what i can tell I have everything correct.  Since the directory will be a variable I rather just have it save in the current folder.

Ultimately I want it as Week # m-d-yy Site.xlsm
e.i Week 36 9-5-20 41st HMU

```
Sub SaveWorkBook()


    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim sSite As String

    dDate = Date 'Todays date
    sSite = Range("Q10").Value 'Site Name
    
    myFile = "Week " & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(dDate, 2) & Format(dDate, "m-d-yy") & " " & sSite & ".xlsm"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName = myFile
  
End Sub
```

Comment: You got the wrong function. Try `WorksheetFunction.ISOWeekNum(Date)`. `dDate` isn't needed. `Wb` isn't used. `MyFile` is misnamed: should be `MyFileName` because `MyFile` is an object. I usually use `Fn` because `FileName:= Fn` is clear enough. Observe the `:=` combination which is required when assigning a value to a named property.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a champ, appreciate it.